# Is High Sierra noticeable slower than Sierra?

Tags: macos, performance

I I have a macbook pro 2012 15" i7 (quad core) with a SSD drive and 16G RAM. Last night I've updated from Sierra to High Sierra and I've noticed that everything seems to be kind of slow. Before the upgrade everything run snappier than now on High Sierra. I just upgraded from the mac app store and not a fresh install of it.

Should I run a fresh install in order to get a better performance?

Comment: Really depends on several factors. What machine are you running this on, what are your specs, is the whole OS slow or is it just a few applications?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Several factors can impact actual or perceived speed of the OS.  The way your question is currently written, it's not possible to provide and accurate answer.  Please see [ask] for tips on writing good questions that can be answered. Otherwise, your question could be closed as either 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion-based'.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response and guidance. 
I have a macbook pro 2012 15" i7 (quad core) with a SSD drive and 16G RAM.
Last night I've updated from Sierra to High Sierra and I've noticed that everything seems to be kind of slow. Before the upgrade everything run snappier than now on High Sierra. I just upgraded from the mac app store and not a fresh install of it. 
Should I run a fresh install in order to get a better performance?
Is there any known noticeable overall performance difference between Sierra and High Sierra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - High Sierra isn’t generally slower than Sierra so there’s likely something else going on.

I like your suggestion to run a fresh install. That’s almost always the fix when a system gets slower and slower and even a fresh install of the same OS as you have running for 6 months to 2 years straight often makes everything snappy and you happy again.

I’d do one last backup and erase install High Sierra and migrate the data back. Take some timings so you know objectively how long a boot takes and how long the things you think are repeatable (opening 5 tabs in Safari / opening a large spreadsheet / etc...) so you can then dig in if the reinstall doesn’t make everything better both subjectively and objectively.

Comment: Thank you a lot about your answer.
I did it that way but is still running slow but the problem seems to be on the SSD or the SATA cable as the speeds are fluctuating from 450MB/s to 200MB/s and oddly the write is faster than the read. I'll go for the SATA flex replacement and crossing my fingers in order to solve the problem that way.
Best regards!